# If else condition in form action

Tags: php, forms, if-statement

Can we use if else condition in form action like this:

```
<form action="<?php if(condition)
{
//redirect to some view file or show error
//run some queries

}
else
{
//redirect to another view
}
 ?>" method="post">
```

Comment: yes! you should have just tried it though, the accepted answer will now be "Yes"/"No"???

Comment: Instead of writing the question - you can just test.

Comment: Provided the code within the conditional bodies echos a string that is a valid form action, then yes. I suspect there is more to this question however

Comment: I tried but i am not getting the result. I am still trying. Thank you for answers

Comment: I think i am having problem in query. We can run query too right???

Comment: yes! add that query to your question please, you must have something like `echo $result['url'];` in your if statement though

Comment: POST Your Tried Code @SujanShrestha .

Comment: Problem is solved. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
    <?php if(condition)
    {
//your html code goes here
    echo <<<HTML
<!--some codes-->
    HTML;
    }   else    {
    //your another html code goes here
    echo <<<HTML
<!-- some another codes codes-->
    HTML;
    }
```